# How to bypass a function, when the browser width is resized above a specific size

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm working on a website of mine, that has a header and a filter section on the top of the page. What I'm trying to do is to make the filter section stick to the top of the page when the page is scrolled down, but only if the device/browser is under a specific width, in this case 1000px.

My problem is that i could only figure out how to update the browsers width after it is resized and then refreshed.

```js
document.body.onscroll = scroll;
var navbar = document.getElementById("navbar");
var bodyTop = navbar.offsetTop;
var browserWidth = window.innerWidth;
navbar.innerHTML = browserWidth + " (Current browser width)"

function scroll() {
  if (browserWidth < 1000) {
    if (document.documentElement.scrollTop > 65) {
      navbar.style.position = "fixed";
      navbar.style.top = "0";
    }
    if (document.documentElement.scrollTop < 65) {
      navbar.style.position = "relative";
      navbar.style.top = "0";
    }
  }
};
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 2000px;
}

#header {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: darkred;
  height: 65px;
  position: relative;
}

#navbar {
  width: 100%;
  height: 85px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<div id="header"></div>
<div id="navbar"></div>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. Plase add relevant HTML in a [mcve]

Comment: if the user resize the browser over 1000px, without refreshing the page, the function will still run, and that is not what i want.

Comment: consider using `@media only screen and (max-width: 1000px)`

Comment: @mplungjan this is the only elements in my document:     <div id="header"></div>
    <div id="navbar"></div>

Comment: @OmriAttiya that might work to, but someone found a simple solution to my code bellow. thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `onresize` event to update the value of `browserWidth` whenever the window is resized:

```
document.body.onscroll = scroll;

var navbar = document.getElementById("navbar");
var bodyTop = navbar.offsetTop;
var browserWidth = window.innerWidth;
navbar.innerHTML = browserWidth + " (Current browser width)"

window.onresize = function() {
    browserWidth = window.innerWidth; //update value of browserWidth
}

function scroll() {
  if (browserWidth < 1000) {
    if (document.documentElement.scrollTop > 65) {
      navbar.style.position = "fixed";
      navbar.style.top = "0";
    }
    if (document.documentElement.scrollTop < 65) {
      navbar.style.position = "relative";
      navbar.style.top = "0";
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: Thank you, this works just fine :) ! Strange that this event didn't show up on google after all my searchings. i thought i would have to target the window object with the "onchange" event or something